# Is it safe to use Truecrypt to encrypt a raid 5 array?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, software-raid

I have a raid 5 array(software in windows server 2008). I have encrypted it using truecrypt, and it seams to be working fine, however, I am worried what will happen when i lose a drive. Will truecrypt mount the volume after a raid rebuild, or would it currypt the encryption? Is using truecrypt on raid volume safe?

Comment: As with any sort of array for redundancy, **TEST IT** - Have a hard drive/cable "fail", and make sure it rebuilds itself, before trusting it with your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RAID 5 is designed to secure arbitrary data transparently, it will rebuild just like any other file system/data format.

There is only one caveat that might apply (depending on your setup):
If the software RAID sits on individually encrypted drives, make sure to encrypt the new one before adding it to the RAID, to avoid writing unencrypted data to it.

If there is a single TrueCrypt volume sitting on top of the RAID, you can add the new drive as normal and the data will be restored in an encrypted state.

Answer (score 0):

As your data is encapsulated within the RAID the only issue you should encounter is the usual performance overhead as every file being written to disk is being encrypted and decrypted by TrueCrypt.

> Will truecrypt mount the volume after a raid rebuild?

Yes, because TrueCrypt does not see the individual disks, only the disk array as a whole, like the OS.

> Is using truecrypt on raid volume safe?

The fault tolerance of the RAID has not changed. Unless you forget your TrueCrypt password or lose your keyfile (or both!) it's as safe as encrypting a single disk or file container.